# Displaying rows in SQL Server where COUNT = 0

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

The following query only returns Region Names for regions where there have been orders.

```
   SELECT r.RegionName,
          COUNT (DISTINCT o.uid)
     FROM Orders AS o
LEFT JOIN Customers AS c ON o.CustomerID = c.uid
LEFT JOIN Regions AS r ON c.Region = r.uid
    WHERE (r.RegionName NOT LIKE 'NULL') 
      AND (r.RegionName <> '') 
      AND (r.RegionName NOT LIKE 'Region 1') 
      AND (o.DateOrdered LIKE '7%2011%')
 GROUP BY r.RegionName
 ORDER BY r.RegionName
```

How can I modify it so that all region names show up even when the "COUNT" is "0"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to either change your `JOIN` to Regions to be a `RIGHT JOIN` or make Regions the `FROM` table and then `JOIN` to the other tables from there.

I prefer the second method, since it seems more intuitive to me. You care about Regions here and you're trying to get information about Regions, so that should be in the `FROM` (IMO):

```
SELECT
    R.RegionName,
    COUNT(O.uid)
FROM
    Regions R
LEFT OUTER JOIN Customers C ON C.Region = R.uid  -- I really don't like this naming convention
LEFT OUTER JOIN Orders O ON
    O.CustomerID = C.uid AND
    O.DateOrdered LIKE '7%2011%'  -- Is your date really stored as a string? Ugh!
WHERE
    R.RegionName <> 'NULL' AND   -- This is VERY bad...
    R.RegionName <> '' AND
    R.RegionName <> 'Region 1'
GROUP BY
    R.RegionName
ORDER BY
    R.RegionName
```

Comment: +1. Comments: I think R.RegionName <> 'NULL' AND R.RegionName <> '' can be ommited since Region is the main table. Also DISTINCT O.uid can be ommited if there is only one row for each order.

Comment: You're right, if uid is the PK for Orders then that can be omitted. I figured that the "NULL" and "''" were to account for bad data in the Regions table, but maybe I'm wrong there.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance.  Naming and field types and missing data out of my control unfortunatly.

Comment: Normally, RegionName column should not be NULL, blank or have any duplicates.

Comment: Suggestion: @Scott maybe you should update the field with the data missing and then make a unique constraint.