# Joining two tables with count and where doesn't return rows with count 0

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a SQL problem. my query looks like:

```
Select 
    s.idseminar, count(p.seminar)
From 
    Seminar as s 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    Predbiljezba AS p ON p.seminar = s.idSeminar 
WHERE 
    p.obradjena = 1
Group by 
    s.idSeminar


idseminar: 1, 2
count....: 2, 2
```

It should display number of accepted applications (`predbiljezba` with `obradjena = 1` <== accepted status) for courses (seminar). It does almost what I need.

What I want is for it to display all the courses even if the number of accepted subscriptions is 0. If I omit the where clause:

```
Select 
    s.idseminar, count(p.seminar)
From 
    Seminar as s 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    Predbiljezba AS p ON p.seminar = s.idSeminar
Group by 
    s.idSeminar


idSeminar: 1,2,3,4       
count....: 2,2,1,0
```

it displays all the courses even if it it has 0 applications, but in these applications there are some that were not processed or were rejected and I do not want them to pop up in my query. I've found this link

[Displaying rows in SQL Server where COUNT = 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6615904/displaying-rows-in-sql-server-where-count-0)

but the solution there doesn't seem to work. I'm using SQL Server 2012.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use subselect in the main select clause

```
Select s.idseminar, 
   (select count(p.seminar) 
   from Predbiljezba p
   where p.seminar = s.idSeminar and p.obradjena = 1) as seminarCount
from Seminar s
```

Answer (score 1):

Move the condition into the LEFT JOIN

```
Select s.idseminar, count(p.seminar)
From Seminar as s
LEFT OUTER JOIN Predbiljezba AS p ON p.seminar = s.idSeminar AND p.obradjena = 1
Group by s.idSeminar
```